# Textbox Postback conflicting with add_endRequest - Hanging Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Working on an ASP.NET website.

I have a textbox defined as....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="daterangepicker" AutoPostBack="true" name="daterangepicker" 
runat="server" Width="110px" BackColor="#ff80ff80"></asp:TextBox>
```

This textbox is within an UpdatePanel (with many other controls). To this textbox I apply a jQuery daterangepicker....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        processDateRangePicker();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        processDateRangePicker();
    });

    function processDateRangePicker() {
      $.getScript("../DateRangePicker/daterangepicker.js", function () {
      $('input[name="ctl00$PageContent$daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
                "linkedCalendars": false,
                   :
```

FYI: The add_endRequest reapplies the jQuery affect to the textbox, otherwise it's lost after postback.

PROBLEM: When the page is loading it is in an endless loop. The add_endRequest event keeps firing. But, when AutoPostBack="false" the page does NOT hang. Everything works fine.

(I'd prefer AutoPostBack to be true because I want the updatepanel's progress indicator to appear when it's "processing".)

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you need to have an autopostback? Cannt you rather solve the progress indicator via jquery

Comment: @ShareYourKnowledge The existing application uses the same UpdatePanel with progress indicator, etc... so I would prefer to keep it the same. But, I suppose if I have to I could use a jQuery implementation.